# JPA LockModeType and @Version

Tags: java, jpa

i have an entity which gets the `@Version / Optimistic Locking` inherited. Now i have observed that an `OptimisticLockException` can be thrown. This occurs because the entity is read and changed. However i don't really care about optimistic locking in this case. What i want is that the last commit wins. My initial try was to set the lock mode type for the query like this:

```
myQuery.setLockMode(LockModeType.None);
```

However i still get the Optimistic lock exception. I don't really understand what is happening here. I thought setting it to none should cause the entity to have no lock at all. I hope somebody can explain me what the problem is here and how i can fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what vendor are you using? OpenJPA does the optimistic locking even without version fields as far as I rememeber

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201940/how-to-disable-the-lock-system-of-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following Annotation: `@OptimisticLock(excluded=true)`. See documentation: [Hibernate Documentation for OptimisticLock Annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLock.html).